# Add controller for "plugin::users-permissions.user" [strapi v4]

Tags: strapi

I can create a controller for created contentType, ex: `api::restaurant.restaurant`.
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html

But for built-in plugins, ex: `plugin::users-permissions.user`, I don't know where to put the controller.

---

**Strapi Version**: 4.0.2